# Sqoop export is not honoring the --columns argument

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I have a sqoop job where I only want to export 3 columns from a HIVE table into mysql table that has only these 3 fields.

```
export --connect <table> --username <U> --password <p>
--table target --columns "col1,col2,col3" --export-dir /path/to/source/table
```

Note that col1, col2, col3 have some fields between them in the hive table.

The error thats thrown is an `IllegalArgumentException`, because Sqoop is parsing a string field between col1 and col2 in the hive table, that I am explicitly trying to ignore, and trying to store it as a timestamp.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having trouble because `--columns` is not meant for what you're trying to do.

When exporting data using `sqoop`, `--columns` allows you to specify what columns in the **target** you will be "affecting". It has nothing to do with the source (in your case, Hive).

Running `sqoop help export`, you get just a brief description of that option:

```
--columns <col,col,col...>                                Columns to
                                                          export to
                                                          table
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!